# Strange performance problem with UPDATE in ArangoDB

Tags: database-performance, query-performance, arangodb, aql, arangojs

I am creating a Node.js application that works with ArangoDB as data store. Basically, what I have as data structure is two tables, one for managing so-called `instances`, another one for `entities`. What I do is the following:

- There is a document in the `instances` collection for every `instance` I have.
- Whenever I add an entity to the `entities` collection, I also want to keep track of the entities that belong to a specific instance.
- So, every `instance` document has an array field for `entities`, and I push the ID of the entity into that array.

The following code shows the general outline:

```js
// Connect to ArangoDB.
db = new Database(...);
db.useBasicAuth(user, password);

// Use the database.
await db.createDatabase(database);
db.useDatabase(database);

// Create the instance collection.
instanceCollection = db.collection(`instances-${uuid()}`);
await instanceCollection.create();

// Create the entities collection.
entityCollection = db.collection(`entities-${uuid()}`);
await entityCollection.create();

// Setup an instance.
instance = {
  id: uuid(),
  entities: []
};

// Create the instance in the database.
await db.query(aql`
  INSERT ${instance} INTO ${instanceCollection}
`);

// Add lots of entities.
for (let i = 0; i < scale; i++) {
  // Setup an entity.
  const entity = {
    id: uuid()
  };

  // Update the instance.
  instance.entities.push(entity);

  // Insert the entity in the database.
  await db.query(aql`
    INSERT ${entity} INTO ${entityCollection}
  `);

  // Update the instance in the database.
  await db.query(aql`
    FOR i IN ${instanceCollection}
      FILTER i.id == ${instance.id}
      UPDATE i WITH ${instance} IN ${instanceCollection} OPTIONS { mergeObjects: false }
  `);
}
```

The problem now is that this becomes extremely slow the more entities I add. It basically has exponential growth, although I would have expected linear growth:

```
Running benchmark 'add and update'
  100 Entities:   348.80ms [+0.00%]
 1000 Entities:  3113.55ms [-10.74%]
10000 Entities: 90180.18ms [+158.54%]
```

Adding an index has an effect, but does not change anything on the overall problem:

```
Running benchmark 'add and update with index'
  100 Entities:   194.30ms [+0.00%]
 1000 Entities:  2090.15ms [+7.57%]
10000 Entities: 89673.52ms [+361.52%]
```

The problem can be tracked down to the `UPDATE` statement. If you leave it out and only use the database's `INSERT` statement, things scale linearly. So, something seems to be wrong with the update itself. However, I don't understand where the problem is.

This is what I would like to understand: Why does the `UPDATE` statement get dramatically slower over time? Am I using it wrong? Is this a known problem in ArangoDB? …?

What I am *not* interested in is discussing this approach: Please take is as given. Let's focus on the performance of the `UPDATE` statement. Any ideas?

#### UPDATE

As asked for in the comments, here some information on the system setup:

- ArangoDB 3.4.6, 3.6.2.1, and 3.7.0-alpha.2 (all running in Docker, on macOS and Linux)
- Single-server setup
- ArangoJS 6.14.0 (we also had this with earlier versions, although I can't tell the exact version)

Comment: Golo, can you give some more info about your environment? What version of ArangoDB are you using? Is this a Cluster or Single-Server? What version of arangojs are you using? With this information, I can check with the engineers. We do long-running crud tests with Java clients that do not show this behavior. Therefore it would be good to get as much info as possible about your environment.

Comment: @fceller Thanks for your response . I've added the information you asked for in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by `use the database's ADD statement`? There is no ADD operation or function to my best knowledge. Do you mean something like this? `LET scale = 10000 RETURN (FOR i IN 1..scale RETURN { id: i })`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo – should have been `INSERT` instead of `ADD`. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

## Finding the problem

Have you tried [explaining or profiling](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.6/aql/execution-and-performance-explaining-queries.html) the query?

Arango's explan plan descriptions are excellent. You can access `explain` using the built-in Aardvark web admin interface, or using `db._explain(query)`. Here's what yours looks like:

```
Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                  Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                1   * ROOT
  5   CalculationNode              1     - LET #5 = { "_key" : "123", "_id" : "collection/123", "_rev" : "_aQcjewq---", ...instance }   /* json expression */   /* const assignment */
  2   EnumerateCollectionNode      2     - FOR i IN collection   /* full collection scan, projections: `_key`, `id` */   FILTER (i.`id` == "1")   /* early pruning */
  6   UpdateNode                   0       - UPDATE i WITH #5 IN pickups 

Indexes used:
 By   Name      Type      Collection   Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields       Ranges
  6   primary   primary   pickups      true     false       100.00 %   [ `_key` ]   i
```

### The problem

The key part in the plan is `- FOR i IN collection   /*`**`full collection scan`**
Full collection scan will be ...slow. It should grow linearly with the size of your collection. So with your `for` loop of `scale` iterations, this definitely means exponential growth with the size of the collection.

## Solution

Indexing the `id` should help but I think it depends on how you created the index.

Using `_key` instead of index changes the plan to show `primary`

```
- FOR i IN pickups   /* primary index scan, index only, projections: `_key` */
```

This should be constant-time, so with your `for` loop of `scale` iterations, this should mean linear time.

Comment: Is there a way to use the explain feature also within transactions?

Comment: I do not think that the plan produced by 'explain' factors in any locking or additional overhead from transactions. It reveals the strategy that the db will use for working through the query. That being said, transactions will not affect that strategy.